# Magento 2 migration Order created at date error

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool, magento2.3.0

I have migrated my magento 1 website to magento 2.3. I have multiple stores in my magento1 with diffrent timezone. After migration when i checked orders in magento 2. There is order creation date changes and this change is specific to stores(Some store have 5.30 hours difference and some have 6.30) plus and minus both. Can anybody suggest me to solve this issue that migrated order created at date should be same like magento1.

Comment: I am facing same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: i didn't get any solution till now.